# DeviceNotRegistered: "ExponentPushToken[***]" is not a registered push notification recipient

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement expo push notifications on react native app built with expo !
I did everything mentioned on their [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/) ! i'm getting the token successfully but when i try sending a push notification to that token using their api or the tool they provide i get this error

`DeviceNotRegistered: "ExponentPushToken[***]" is not a registered push notification recipient`

This is how i'm getting the token !

```
export const useNotifications = () => {
  const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
    if (Device.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } =
        await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
        return;
      }
      const token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
      console.log("TOKEN------------", token);
      alert(token);
    } else {
      alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    }

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
        name: "default",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
      });
    }
  };
   const handleNotification = (notification = Notifications.Notification) => {
    // could be useful if you want to display your own toast message
    // could also make a server call to refresh data in other part of the app
  };

  // This listener is fired whenever a user taps on or interacts with a notification (works when app is foregrounded, backgrounded, or killed)
  const handleNotificationResponse = (
    response = Notifications.NotificationResponse
  ) => {
    const data = ({ url } = response.notification.request.content.data);

    if (data?.url) Linking.openURL(data.url);
  };
  return {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync,
    handleNotification,
    handleNotificationResponse,
  };
};
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
    Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
      handleNotification: async () => ({
        shouldShowAlert: true,
        shouldPlaySound: false,
        shouldSetBadge: true,
      }),
    });
    const responseListener =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
        handleNotificationResponse
      );

    return () => {
      if (responseListener) {
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

i run the eas build  `eas build -p android --profile preview`  so i can test it on a real device since push notifications works only on real devices and after that i pushed the cloud messaging server key that i got from my firebase project  with this command  `expo push:android:upload --api-key <your-token-here>`

As i said i successfully get the token but the i get the error when trying to send the notification!
am i missing a step or something ?
I tried run the build on two devices and both not working !

Answer (score 0):

I hade similar situation, what I did different from you is that I run expo build to create apk after putting FCM server key in expo project credentials